# Rechecking a file for updated content

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to recheck a file on a timed interval. I'm not sure if this can be accomplished, but any help would be greatly appreciated. I understand that as PHP is server-sided, it cannot accomplish my task, so anything with JavaScript is fine.

By rechecking a file, I mean getting a file's contents, but only if it's updated. Somewhat like "if file gets new contents, output them."

Comment: you mean like...this? http://livejs.com/

Comment: Let me be a little more in-depth with this. It's similar to that, except by rechecking a file, I mean getting a file's contents, but only if it's updated. Somewhat like "if file gets new contents, output them."

Comment: JavaScript is run in a security sandbox in the browser and usually doesn't have file system access.

Comment: Could I integrate PHP with JavaScript to do so?

Comment: a file on a server or a file on the user's device?

Comment: File on a server, but I've got it now. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are checking on a remote file, then the PHP solution would be best: simply send the file and its checksum, then when the checksum changes, the file has been updated.

If you're working with a local file, then (if I'm seeing things right) you'll need a browser with the HTML5 File API. May be a duplicate of this: [Check if file has changed using HTML5 File API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284124/check-if-file-has-changed-using-html5-file-api)

Comment: It's in the same directory, and thinking of that, I could use FileSize to see if it updated, hmm. Thanks :P